# How to make Oracle VM Virtual Box full screen?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

These are my settings:
[image]

This is how I see my screen:
[image]

I have tried each vga option from dropdown but nothing helps
[image]

`Scale factor` does not help because it looks ugly.

AM I missing something? How  to make it full screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to insert Guest Addition CD in your VM, install software from this CD in Ubuntu and reboot VM.

[image]

Comment: Thansk, will try